# Why is there intermittent 502 for nodejs application

Tags: node.js, aws-application-load-balancer

I have receving intermitant 502 for nodejs application. The application is running as a container in ECS.

When looking at the ALB access log request_processing_time is 0, the target_processing_time is 0, and the response_processing_time is -1. elb_status_code is 502 and target_status_code is empty

I did have a look at this article https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-alb-troubleshoot-502-errors but does not match any condition mentioned in the article.

Is there way to find why nodejs suddenly becomes non responsive?